# Scala code slows down as array size increases

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have written a Scala Spark application that is implementation of iterative algorithm. Element wise operation have to be performed in each iteration on arrays. Initially size of all collection was 1000. For 1000 size arrays, code works fine and faster. Now size of arrays is **1 million** and this code (part of application) is taking too long time, slowing down whole application. This code is used inside **mapPartitionWithIndex** of Spark RDD. Here is code.

```
def ESt(arr: Array[Double], arr1: Array[Double], frq: Double): Array[Double] = {
 val newArr = new Array[Double](arr.length)
 var i = 0
 while (i < arr.length) {
  newArr(i) = (arr(i) - arr1(i)) * frq
  i += 1
 }
 newArr
}


def ES(arr: Array[Double], arr1: Array[Double], arr2: Array[Double]): Array[Double] = {
 val newArr =new Array[Double](arr.length)
 var i = 0
 while (i < arr.length) {
  newArr(i) = arr(i) + arr1(i) + arr2(i)
  i += 1
 }
 newArr
}
```

Here is usage of above two functions to create an Array.

```
val dim = 1000000 // one million
val number : Double = math.random
val xr1 : Array[Double] = Array of size dim
val xr2 : Array[Double] = Array of size dim
val xbest : Array[Double] = Array of size dim
val randomArray : Array[Double] = Array.fill(dim)(math.random)

var result : Array[Double] = ES(randomArray, ESt(xbest, randomArray, number), ESt(xr1, xr2, number))
```

I have lot of cores in cluster where I executes this code. How can I speed-up this computation using Scala functional or parallel programming power or using any other technique?

Comment: What of all this has to do with **Spark**? Also, if you have an **O(N)** algorithm it is not a surprise that it becomes slower as the size increases. - The way to speed this is that since each element of the array is independent of each other this is _"trivially"_ parallelizable, how to do that would depend on your parallelization strategy, if you are using **Spark** you may have an RDD of **Arrays** as such use smaller arrays so more cores can process, other option would be to flatten everything and do a join between two RDDs to make the same process.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I have a huge population. Spark is used to distribute population to sub populations. Above mentioned code executes on each partition.

Comment: The yeah as I said the best is to ensure that each subpopulation is small so you end up with more subpopulations each one on its own executor, and thus increasing parallelism and reducing execution time. - If you can not, then you may ensure each executor to have more cores and parallelize the code yourself using **Futures** or the parallel collections.

Comment: Due to algorithm performance limitations, I can set partitions more than 20.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the fact that you have little partitions is what makes your algorithm slow, not sure why you can not increase them. But anyway, as I said the alternative would be to ensure each **Executor** to have multiple cores and parallelize that while yourself.